# Code completion for static methods in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Is there a way to get auto completion in eclipse for static methods? IntelliJ offers this feature. For example:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public static class SomeClassBuilder {
        public static SomeClassBuilder builder() { ... }

        public SomeClass build() { ... }
    }

}

SomeClass someClass = SomeClass.SomeClassBuilder.builder().build();
```

In IntelliJ you start typing `build`<<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd>> and the autocompletion popup suggests `SomeClass.SomeClassBuilder.builder()` amongst others.

In eclipse is possible to get the same result by adding SomeClass.SomeClassBuilder to the Favourites. But if I have hundreds of these builders in my projects, I don't want to add them manually to the favourites.

Is there any plugin in eclipse that offers such facility?
Please avoid answers like "Use IntelliJ", since the question is about achieving the result in eclipse. Thanks

Comment: i believe eclipse already has that feature..

Answer (score -3):

Eclipse has the feature you describe.

To use autocomplete on a static method e.g. `Class.staticMethod()`. Simply start typing `Class.` in the *Java editor*. Once the `.` is typed, Eclipse will present the list of all available `static` methods for class `Class`. You can also press `ctrl-space` after the `.`.

The Java editor, autocomplete, and much more is included in the [Eclipse JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/). The JDT is very likely installed in your Eclipse distribution.

Comment: I would like "staticMethod()" to be suggested **without** the need to type the class it belongs to. In the example of the post, I would like to just type "staticMethod" and the autocompletion to suggest all the classes where staticMethod() appear as public static method

Comment: That is not possible in Eclipse